# C: function skips user input in code

Tags: c, loops, char, printf, scanf

I am having a problem with this function (part of a Battleship game) where it will run through it once perfectly fine, but in subsequent executions, it skips:

```
    scanf("%c",&rChar);
```

For some reason, rChar turns into another value without user input from above code.
I have tried putting in `printf` statements showing the value of rChar all throughout the function.

The function `Conv_rChar_Int()` converts the Char the user inputs into an integer value. But because `rChar` isn't being passed around as a pointer, the value of `rChar` remains the same throughout until the user replaces it on the next iteration. (Verified yet again with `printf`). The weird thing is, it changes right in between these lines of code. and never prompts the user for `rChar`.

```
    printf("please enter the row you want to place your %d ship in\n",length);
    scanf("%c",&rChar);
```

Remember, it only happens AFTER the first time.  Even if I reinitialize the variables `rChar`, `r`, `c`, and `dir` after every iteration, this problem still happens. 
I am 99% certain the problem is within this function and not in any of the functions that gets called within it (because `rChar` remains the same after every single line except between the 2 lines above).

Thanks for help in advance. If you have any questions about the code I'll try to explain it more.

```
int Gen_Ship_Place(int length, int flag3, int PlayGrid[10][10]){
int ShipPlaceFlag = 0;

//coordinates and direction
int r;
char rChar;
int c;
int dir;

//this loops until a ship location is found
while(ShipPlaceFlag == 0)
{
    //enters row
    printf("please enter the row you want to place your %d ship in\n",length);
    scanf("%c",&rChar);

    r = Conv_rChar_Int(rChar);

    //adjusts row
    r--;
    //enter column
    printf("please enter the column you want to place your %d ship in\n",length);
    scanf("%d",&c);

    //adjust column
    c--;

    //enter direction
    printf("please enter the direction you want your %d ship to go\nwith\n0 being north\n1 being east\n2 being south\n3 being west\n",length);

    scanf("%d",&dir);

    //checks ship placement
    ShipPlaceFlag = Check_Ship_Place(length,dir,flag3,r,c,PlayGrid);

    //tells player if the location is wrong or not
    if(ShipPlaceFlag == 0)
    {
        printf("****the location and direction you have chosen is invalid please choose different coordinates, here is your current board*****\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("****great job, here is your current board*****\n\n");
    }

    //prints grid so player can check it for their next move
    Print_Play_Grid(PlayGrid);

}
```

Comment: http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-60.html

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfc.html ... and for the love of god, please stop using `scanf`.

Answer (score 4):

Your program prints this prompt:

```
please enter the row you want to place your 2 ship in
```

and calls `scanf`. You type `5` and press return.  You have typed in **two** characters: the `5` and a newline character `\n`.  (Or maybe it's `\r` on Windows.)  That newline character sits in the input buffer until the next call to `scanf`, which reads the newline character and returns right away without you needing to enter more input.

You can make `scanf` skip past newlines (and other whitespace) when reading a single character by putting a space before the `%c` specifier, like this:

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

Comment: Nice -- hadn't thought of that.

Comment: As ever - use `fgets()` to read a line of input and then `sscanf()` to parse it.  Or at least loop with `getchar()` to read to the newline after each character, or ... something along those general lines.

Answer (score 1):

When the user presses enter, that is also a character which will be in the input buffer.  You'll need to read past that.

```
//prints grid so player can check it for their next move
Print_Play_Grid(PlayGrid);
while (fgetc(stdin)!='\n') { }
```